# Redis.Redis is giving warning "Redis only refers to a type but using as a namespace here"

Tags: typescript, redis

my code is like this
what should I do to remove this error, I am using typescript here.

```
    import Redis, { Cluster, ClusterNode, ClusterOptions } from 'ioredis';

    import config from '.';

export class RedisConfig {

private readonly READY_STATUS = 'ready';

    private readonly redis: Redis.Redis | Cluster;  // error is here

    private maxRetries?: number;
```

I want to remove that error, how to remove this?

Comment: Did you try? `private readonly redis: Redis | Cluster;`

Comment: yes tried now error is clear now thank you